# Disable a button upon condition in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am a beginner to Apps Script. I am doing a resident payment system where the user will enter username and password first and after logging in they can view the payment history. For now the Paypal button will just show although they have paid until current month. Can anyone help me to modify the coding where if the user have paid for the current month then the paypal button would not show in that web app. I have attached link to my Apps Script to explain myself better.

https://script.google.com/d/1xV7FDVgp10XbGFtPJDUnhqm1GYybKZeKEI2L84Slp34rndOWgVJ1iScm/edit?usp=sharing - Link to my Apps Script coding

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxFJTD9f6cMMDYDHw5sY6bENOmC52Z_7-mkGmnNGkQ-B5-j-63Q4aOcgetX4MWYIfW6/exec - Link to my executed version (Web App)

USERNAME : JJACKSON

PASSWORD : PASSWORD1

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While including links might be helpful questions should be self-contained so please add a [mcve] showing what you tried. regarding the question. Also add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the value of `PAID` of the column "Payment Status" is existing in the current month and current year, you don't want to show the button of PayPal.

#### Modification points:

- From your script, it seems that the button of PayPal is shown with the script of `document.getElementById("digitalgoods-030521182921-1").style.display = "block";`. In this case, I thought that it is required to run this script by the condition you expect.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify the function `displayTable` in Javascript side as follows.

From:

```
document.getElementById("digitalgoods-030521182921-1").style.display = "block";
```

To:

```
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth();
if (!ar.some(([a,,,d]) => {
  var t = new Date(a);
  return year == t.getFullYear() && month == t.getMonth() && d.toUpperCase() == "PAID";
})) {
  document.getElementById("digitalgoods-030521182921-1").style.display = "block";
}
```

#### Reference:

- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Thank you so much for your helps bro. I mean it bro. You have been very helpful for me to complete this project bro. So thankful that you could understand the problem and help me further.

Comment: I give you one link to my appscript bro everything you thought me is working fine bro. I have made some changes and then it is not working bro. Sorry for disturbing bro but if you have time would you mind going to my appscript and have a look on it.  After doing the changes when I add the coding you have written here, it is compiling bro but then the application is not working. The program is just keep on loading bro. Could you help me to sort it out? I paste a new link for it. Hope you could help me on this. Thank you so much bro.

Comment: https://script.google.com/d/1xV7FDVgp10XbGFtPJDUnhqm1GYybKZeKEI2L84Slp34rndOWgVJ1iScm/edit?usp=sharing  If you managed to find the problem, just edit there and save bro because it is one of my example version so I can copy from there. Thank you bro –

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you so much for being with me and doing this stuffs bro. I mean it. Thank you for being with me throughout this project. I have created a new post bro. Would you help me on it?

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG Thank you for your response. When I could find the solution of your new question, I would like to answer it. If I couldn't find the solution, I apologize for it.

Comment: Sorry bro. Have you thought of the solution for the new problem. Sorry for disturbing you bro.

Comment: Bro just want to clarify something. Is it would be possible to get the from the google sheet for the payment in paypal. For me I am doing a payment system right would it be possible to get the specific address from the google sheet and fill it in the paypal ?

Comment: Bro sorry bro for me its midnight now. I have several new questions bro. If you have time, help me to solve it bro really hoping on you for it.

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG About your new questions, when I could find the solution of your new question, I would like to answer it. If I couldn't find the solution, I apologize for it.

Comment: Okay thank you bro. For now right bro, I guess I need your help first on adding a new a row in google sheet using Google App Script bro. Please help me with it bro. It is actually my school project since I am a beginner in Google App Script your help means alot to me

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG About your new questions, I think that when we could find the solution of your new questions, we will answer it. So, I think that it is not required to make users remind to answer for your questions.

Comment: Owh sorry sorry for making you annoyed bro so sorry. I wont do it again. Sorry

Comment: @LEE WEI LIANG Thank you for understanding it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232673/discussion-between-lee-wei-liang-and-tanaike).